# New release upload fail

Tags: android, google-play-console

so I'm trying to create a new release but I keep getting this error:

> *"You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1."*

Someone said to add `android:versionCode="2"` in android manifest, but I still get the same error. My previous release did not have a version code. I'm wondering if perhaps it's an issue with the version code increment since I don't really know what the `versionCode` defaults to when it is not specified.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `versionCode` and optionally the `versioName`.

```
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
  }
```

Note `versionCode` is a number.

Check this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning